# Problems installing homebrew

Tags: ruby, homebrew

I'm trying to install homebrew on the mac but I can not, has this problem.

```
ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.github.com/gist/323731)"
curl: (6) Couldn't resolve host 'raw.github.com'
```

how can I fix this and install. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just navigate to https://raw.github.com/gist/323731:

> This script has been moved.
>   https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/blob/master/Library/Contributions/install_homebrew.rb

Here is a fresh installation guide: https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/wiki/Installation

---

Update: Now the installation instructions were moved to: http://brew.sh/

Answer (score 0):

http://blog.wyeworks.com/2012/4/13/my-osx-rails-installation-using-homebrew-and-rbenv-step-by-step#comments

This blog is fairly helpful step by step like.   I have been having a tough time as well. I had to download the Snow leopard version under "Option 1" for the original download, the rest of the install has been okay except now I have a path error

Answer (score 0):

Paste that at a Terminal prompt.

```
ruby <(curl -fsSkL raw.github.com/mxcl/homebrew/go)
```

OR  do yourself a favor and install to /usr/local

```
mkdir homebrew && curl -L https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/tarball/master | tar xz --strip 1 -C homebrew
```

OR simply

```
curl -Lsf http://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/tarball/master | tar xz --strip 1 -C /usr/local
```

Please refer to https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/wiki/Installation for more details.